# Non-type template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading an article about non-type template arguments, and it said that :

 When being instantiated, only compile time constant integer can be passed. This means `100`, `100+99`, `1<<3` etc are allowed, since they are compiled time constant expressions. Arguments, that involve function call, like `abs(-120)`, are not allowed.

Example :

```
template<class T, int SIZE>
class Array{};

int main(){
Array<int, 100+99> my_array; // allowed
Array<int, abs(-120)> my_array; // not allowed
}
```

what's the difference between 100+99 and abs(-120) ?
how come 100+99 are compiled time and abs(-120) is not?

Comment: I highly doubt if the integer literal is considered as an object. If yes, I am curious how `C` has done it where concept of operator overloading isn't available.

Comment: If C++ were a pure OO language, yes. But it's not. Go ahead and try `100.operator+(99)` and see what happens.

Comment: The choice of what expression can be evaluated meaningfully at compile-time will at some point necessarily be arbitrary. C++ chooses to be conservative about this, so it's mostly trivial expressions, templates, or other things it knows are "safe". E.g. how could the compiler know whether it makes sense to evaluate `printf("")` at compile-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`100+99` is optimized out to `199` at compile time.

`abs()` is function and it may or may not be marked `constexpr` (C++11 feature, that would allow you to do so; you can easily check cppreference or standard to see if it's `constexpr` in C++11). It requires to be executed; compiler cannot deduce that it's state less function returning same value for every run with same argument.

Comment: If the Standard `abs` is not marked `constexpr`, you can write your own `abs` which can be `constexpr`.

Comment: Apparently there's a constexpr abs in libstdc++, I'm able to use `std::abs(-120)` as a non-type template argument in gcc 4.6.

Comment: @mfontanini, hence my "may or may not be marked"; I don't know whether standard guarantees that.

Comment: @Griwes : why the value of abs(-120) can't be known at compile time ?

Comment: @AlexDan because the compiler has no idea what `abs` does. It's just a function that exists somewhere else.

Comment: `std::abs` is _not_ marked constexpr in the standard. Although I don't think there's anything that prohibits implementations from adding it.

Comment: @bames53 : Im not sure, but I guess it's not marked as constexpr so the client can use it like this. int a=-120; abs(a);

Comment: @AlexDan constexpr functions can be used with non-constexpr parameters. It's just that they aren't actually evaluated at compile time in that case and they don't create constant expressions. The constexpr only says 'if you give me constexpr parameters then I form a constexpr. otherwise I will just be a normal runtime function.'

Answer (score 4):

None, and `abs(-120)` is entirely legal in C++11. C++03, as you adequately point out, did not have scope for functions which could evaluate at compile-time, but C++11 does. For `abs` directly, you could replace it with a template which performs the same computation and use `abs_template<-120>::value` in C++03.

Edit: I meant to say that, even if `abs` was not `constexpr`, you could trivially write your own `abs` which is `constexpr`. Coulda sworn I edited that in.

Comment: Is `abs` defined as `constexpr` in C++11?

Comment: `std::abs` is not defined as `constexpr` as far as I can see.

Comment: why the value of abs(-120) can't be known at compile time ?

Comment: @AlexDan: It is not whether the value can be known at compile time, but whether it can be used as a compile time constant. Consider: `int f() { return 5; }`, that function could be inlined and replace by a 5 at the place of call, but it cannot be used where a constant expression is needed (size of an array, argument to a template)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas : I understand why size of an array must me const expression, sothat the compiler will know how much of memory to allocate for this array in the stack. but what about non-type template argument, what is the need of const expression. is it because template class get created at compile time?

Comment: @AlexDan: Yes, templates are instantiated (and code generated) at compile time.